# Creating tab bar like iPhone on android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

Very new to android. I went through some sites and the official site to create a tabbed view after login screen. But when i create the tabs it says `no tab known for tag null` . Not sure what to do to create 4 tabs.

This is my code.

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and TabActivity.java has this

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabWidget;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class TabActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("Home"),
                DeliverySitesActivity.class, null);
        TabWidget tabWidget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
        if (tabWidget != null) {
            View tabWidgetChild = tabWidget.getChildAt(0);
            if (tabWidgetChild != null) {
                tabWidgetChild.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Where am i going wrong? I need a tab bar in the bottom of the screen. This is my LogCat

```
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.hello.DeliverySitesActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.doTabChanged(FragmentTabHost.java:339)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:276)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:12125)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2450)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2457)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2457)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2457)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1207)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-29 05:45:25.126: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace from Logcat.

Comment: Well then where are you getting "no tab known for tag null"?

Comment: Logcat trace is shared

Comment: You are getting `ClassCastException` because `DeliverySitesActivity` probably not a `Fragment` rather an `Activity`

Comment: I changed it to Fragment but it still gives the same exception

Answer (score 0):

`FragmentTabHost` expects Fragments as the content of tabs, but you are using an Activity class as the content of the tab instead of a Fragment class.

`mTabHost.addTab(... DeliverySitesActivity.class, ...)`